# supply two inputs to set_downstream() in Prefect

Tags: prefect

Right now I have a setup where a third flow depends on two prior flows.

It should look something like

```
third_flow.set_downstream([flow_foo, flow_bar])
```

But instead I have it unnecessarily chained like this:

```
flow_foo.set_downstream(flow_bar)
flow_bar.set_downstream(third_flow)
```

The order that `foo` and `bar` run in doesn't matter, it's only important that they both complete before `third_flow` runs.

What's the best way to express this in Prefect?

*EDIT:* I'm not on Prefect v2 at this point

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. `flow_foo.set_dependencies(task=first_task, upstream_tasks=[another_task, yet_another])` for imperative API
2. Much easier is to set those when you call tasks: `task3(upstream_tasks=[task1, task2])` for functional API

And if you are getting started, it got much easier in Prefect 2 since you can run any Python, no DAG structure required: https://docs.prefect.io

Comment: `flow.set_dependencies()` works for me wonderfully, thank you for this answer.